# Split a column by condition and create new columns python

Tags: pandas, string, split

The original data frame is as

[image]

Class 1 contains

*Intermittent_Bowling Conversion L1_2_Shipper Full Pallet L1_2_Healthy Gandy Transition L1_2_New Year Sme You L1_2_F24 Seasons Party L1_2_Dual HB L1_2_Utopia L1_2_Power Box L1_2_Snarl L1_2_Luti Feeding L1_2_Hot Zone L1_2_Yellow For Life L1_2_End Cap L1_2_Register Lane L1_2_Shipper Quarter Pallet L1_2_Pallet Stack L1_2_Coupon L1_2_Dollars Off L1_2_Price Point L1_2_Discount % L1_1_BOGO L1_2_CountryHolidays Predict_1_CountryHolidaysPublic Predict_1*

I have to convert this Class1 column into new columns and put the number b/w the underscore in it, so it will look like this

[image]

I have tried regex split but some or the other errors keep on occuring and unable to have this as output. Please if possible can anyone help me to figure out the approach.

Edited based on 1st comment, do not know how to add excel table in as it is form here

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input, images of data are not allowed, they don't enable us to help you. We cannot tell what's in `Class1` without ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks, Not sure how to add exact table in here, added the contents of the Class1 in the description

Comment: Assuming `df` your DataFrame, provide the output of `df.head().to_dict('list')`

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an ugly solution:

```py
import pandas

def parse_stuff(line):
    thesplit = line.split('_')
    return {thesplit[i * 2]: thesplit[(i * 2) + 1] for i in range(int(len(thesplit) / 2))}

test_df = pandas.DataFrame([{"a": 1, "b": "Hello world_6_Hi there_3"}])
#    a                         b
# 0  1  Hello world_6_Hi there_3

temp_dict = test_df['b'].apply(parse_stuff).to_dict()
# {0: {'Hello world': '6', 'Hi there': '3'}}

new_df = pandas.DataFrame(temp_dict).transpose()
#   Hello world Hi there
# 0           6        3

test_df = test_df.join(new_df)
#    a                         b Hello world Hi there
# 0  1  Hello world_6_Hi there_3           6        3
```

Note that if column names contain `_`, the code won't work correctly.

Hope that helps.